# LOUD Computer Fan

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, laptop-repair

Toshiba Satellite 9755-S5320 fan completely went out, no warning sign, just turned it on one morning got a message that the cooling system has a problem, get repaired immediately.  I order a new fan pop that puppy in and now sometimes things run silent and smooth, but more often than not it sounds like a weed eater or a small engine.  I feel the cool air blowing out of the vent, and I see the fan spinning with nothing over it.  I even opened the housing again to verify nothing was covering the fan.  Question being, what could be causing the fan to sound this way?

when I opened my case to replace the fan, I blew out all of the dust that had collected inside the case also.

EDIT --
How would I Know the size/speed I would need to attempt a different fan?  For example, (not promoting this location in any way) I see this one online, but how do I know if the size & RPM will work in my scenario?

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/antec-120mm-cpu-cooling-fan-clear/6704373.p?id=1083713296903&skuId=6704373

Comment: Could the fan blades be hitting a cable? (Bit like the engine sound effect we made by attaching folded paper to the spokes on the wheels of our bikes as kids.)

Comment: @JMB - I initially thought that as well, but their is nothing in the vicinity of the fan for it to be hitting, was hoping it would be a quick easy fix like such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either it's improperly installed, it's defective, or the most likely option, it's a cheaply made fan and it just sounds this loud.

My recommendation is to reinstall the fan and make sure everything is screwed down tight. Any looseness will allow for the fan to vibrate and cause an annoying noise. If it doesn't go away then return it for a different fan from another source/vendor.

Comment: I would buy the improperly installed or defective option.  Cheaply made (possible), I ordered the part from here http://www.sparepartswarehouse.com/Toshiba,Laptop,Part,K000121870.aspx